# program to read a file contents

Tags: python, snort

I have a snort log file named "logs" and want to extract IP addresses from it and store them to another file named "blacklist". it can extract unique IP Addresses but if I run the program again, it adds the previous IPs as well. I want the program to first check whether IP is already in blacklist file? if so, just ignore it otherwise add unique IPs from logs file to blacklist. code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
mylist1 = []
mylist2 = []
mylist3 = []
mylist4 = []
logfile = open('/var/log/snort/logs', 'r')
blklist = open('blacklist', 'ab+')

for line in open ('blacklist', 'r').readlines():
  mylist4.append(line)

for l in logfile.readlines():
  l = l.rstrip()
  ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}',l)
  if ip is not None and ip not in mylist1:
    mylist1.append(ip)
for ip in mylist1:
  addr = ",".join(ip)
  if ',' in addr:
    a = addr.split(',')
    for ip in a:
        addr = "".join(ip)
        if addr is not '':
            mylist2.append(addr)
        else:
            mylist3.append(addr)
for x in blklist:
  mylist2.append(x.strip())
for x in mylist2:
  if x not in mylist3 and x not in mylist4:
    blklist.write(x+'\n')
    mylist3.append(x)
```

Logs file is:

```
12/16-10:34:27.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**][classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.40.19 -> 192.168.50.29

12/16-10:34:27.070967 [**] [1:10000001:1] snort alert [1:0000001] [**][classification ID: 0] [Priority ID: 0] {ICMP} 192.168.50.29 -> 192.168.30.20
```

Output of blacklist file after first program run:

```
192.168.30.20
192.168.50.29
192.168.40.19
```

Output of blacklist file after second program run:

```
192.168.30.20
192.168.50.29
192.168.40.19
192.168.30.20
192.168.50.29
192.168.40.19
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read everything in from your blacklist file and log into lists. Join those list and then ouput a set back to the blacklist file (sets are unique values) since the read empties the file your will have a unique list of all new and old IPs. If the order matters (doubt it does) then a set will cause issues. Let me know and I can revamp the below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re
    blacklist = list(open("blacklist", 'r').read().split('\n'))
    logfile = list(open("/var/log/snort/logs", 'r').read().split('\n'))

    newentry = []
    for entry in logfile:
        ips = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', entry)
        for ip in ips:
            newentry.append(ip)

    newblacklist = blacklist + newentry

    with open("blacklist", 'w+') as f:
        f.write('\n' .join(set(newblacklist)))
        f.close()
```

Comment: thanks nerdlyist for your attention. order doesn't matter but the log file is not including only IP addresses so I have to extract only IPs from that. I've included the log file in the question. I really got confused and stacked

Comment: @RAZHamraz couple question how large is this log file. Which or those IPs would you block or is it all of them? If it is not all of them what lets you know you want to block it?

Comment: no it is not all. it includes more IPs. the code in the question can extract them but if I run for second time, it adds duplicated as well... this is real doubt

Comment: So can I add any of the ip address found in the log to the blacklist?

Comment: yeah sure you can.

Comment: I tried but got error in third line (blacklist = list...). the error msg is: AttributeError: 'buitin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Check the path for blacklist. I tested it successfully

Comment: finally done... thank you so much @nerdlyist for all explanations and attention to solve this issue. I really appreciate such people.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the Python container type `set` which stores only unique elements. The procedure below should work for you:

```
create a 'current' blacklist set
read the blacklist file IP's into the current set

create a 'delta' blacklist set

for each IP address in the log file
  if not already in current blacklist
    add the IP into the delta set

append (by writing) the delta set into the black list file
```